# subprocess Popen().stdout.readline() hangs forever

Tags: python, subprocess

For background, I am using Windows 10 python3.

If I run the command on CMD, it works just fine.

But when I use `subprocess` module...

```
import subprocess
import os

command = [r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark\tshark.exe', '-Y', 'ip.src==192.168.1.19 && ip.dst==192.168.1.24', '-i', 'Wi-Fi', '-T',  'fields', '-e', 'data']

process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=open(os.devnull, "w"))
try:
    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline()  # hangs forever
        if process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if line:
            print(line)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print(process.stdout.readlines())  # prints everything that wouldn't print earlier
```

`process.stdout.read()` also hangs forever.

I literally get all the output when I hit `CTRL+C`...

I understand there are so many similar questions here in Stack Overflow but none seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Are you sure your subprocess is sending lines to its STDOUT? Maybe set a timeout?

Comment: Yes, all the lines are printed at once after hitting `CTRL+C`. `process.stdout.readlines()`

Comment: Try `process.stdout.read(1)`?

Comment: It also hangs. Buffering must be happening at the PIPE. When I don't set `stdout = subprocess.PIPE` output can be seen in terminal right away

Comment: maybe the problem is stderr? try using `subprocess.DEVNULL` instead of an open file descriptor?